# how to configure usb to hdmi in ubuntu 18?

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, hdmi, playonlinux

I want to connect my external monitor with my laptop using an USB to HDMI device, a Fresco Logic inc. FL2000 USB to HDMI adapter (identified by lsusb as it shows **Bus 002 Device 005: ID 1d5c:2000**) but I don't know how to get it work with Ubuntu 18.04.3

How do I use that adapter to send video to an HDMI monitor?

Comment: Not sure "configure" is the right idea. First thing I'd try is `lsusb` to see if the device is detected.

Comment: yes it is detecting the device. 
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 1d5c:2000

Comment: The last driver which worked was for Ubuntu 14.04 which is no longer supported. See https://github.com/FrescoLogic/FL2000

Answer (score 0):

The security maintenance of Ubuntu 14.04 has been extended for an additional 3 years of extended security maintenance (ESM) until April, 2022. Anyone can use Ubuntu Advantage Infrastructure Essential which includes Ubuntu 14.04 ESM for free for personal use on up to 3 machines (limitations apply). All you need is an Ubuntu One account.

Then you can install the [Fresco Logic FL2000 Linux/Android Kernel driver](https://github.com/FrescoLogic/FL2000) for your Fresno Logic USB to HDMI device in Ubuntu 14.04.